# Timer overflow on MSP430

Tags: c, msp430, interrupts

I'm using an interrupt to wake the microcontroller once the value has been reached. I see that in the Capture/Compare Control Register there is a Capture Overflow bit. I can't seem to find an example of checking for this bit once the value has been reached. One [example](http://mspsci.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/tutorial-10-b-interrupt-examples.html) interrupt looked like:

```
#pragma vector = TIMERA0_VECTOR
__interrupt void CCR0_ISR(void) {
    if (++i == 120) {
        P1OUT ^= RLY1;
        i=0;
    }
} // CCR0_ISR
```

But this doesn't check the value of the bit. So how do i check to see if the timer has overflowed?

Comment: Presumably the rest of the example sets the timer into a mode where overflow is the only interrupt event. So, if the timer didn't overflow you didn't get to this code.

Comment: could you please tell wat your exact output was??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure exactly which series MSP you're using so you'll have to look up the specifics. But the basic premise should apply across the board I think.

The following example is from the file `msp430g2xx1_ta_03.c` in the code snippets that can be downloaded from the [TI Wiki](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/MSP430_LaunchPad_%28MSP-EXP430G2%29#Code_examples.2FSnippets):

```
#include <msp430.h>

int main(void)
{
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                 // Stop WDT
  P1DIR |= 0x01;                            // P1.0 output
  TACTL = TASSEL_2 + MC_2 + TAIE;           // SMCLK, contmode, interrupt

  _BIS_SR(LPM0_bits + GIE);                 // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupt
}

// Timer_A3 Interrupt Vector (TAIV) handler
#pragma vector=TIMERA1_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer_A(void)
{
 switch( TAIV )
 {
   case  2: break;                          // CCR1 not used
   case  4: break;                          // CCR2 not used
   case 10: P1OUT ^= 0x01;                  // overflow
            break;
 }
}
```

The key is checking the `TAIV` register to see what caused the interrupt. Take a look at page 416 of the [CC430 Family User's Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau259e/slau259e.pdf):

[image: TAIV Register Description]

Now the code example is looking for a value of `10` in the `TAIV` register and the User Guide indicates that `0x0E` is the overflow. So, again, check your specific chip's documentation. But the `TAIV` register is what will tell you what the cause of the interrupt is.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 interrupt sources for Timer A

1. Timer Overflow   `#pragma vector = TIMERA0_VECTOR`
2. Capture/compare interrupt  `#pragma vector = TIMERA1_VECTOR`

Interrupt routine you are looking will be executed when timer overflows and not when compare register is matched with TAR. 
You should use check TAIV register in

```
    #pragma vector = TIMERA1_VECTOR
__interrupt void CCR0_ISR(void) 
{
 //check TAIV for compare/capture interrupt
}
```